# JavaFX Timeline Cycle Listener

Tags: javafx

is there a way to get the information when the next round of a cycle starts? The onFinish method of the timeline is not working for infinite cycles.

My only idea is to use the currentTimeProperty and check if the value increases or decreases.

Thanks for your help
Hauke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a event handler to the last [`KeyFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html) (or modify a existing one) to run a event when the `Timeline` animation restarts, e.g. change

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(node.translateXProperty(), 0)),
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(node.translateXProperty(), 300))
);

timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

to

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(node.translateXProperty(), 0)),
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), evt -> System.out.println("finished"), new KeyValue(node.translateXProperty(), 300))
);

...
```

to print `"finished"` after every cycle.